# Kusto: can I count distinct number of values for an arbitrary set of columns

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to count the distinct count of each custom value in AppInsights telemetry with Kusto.
`customDimensions` property can contain several fields, not constrained by name or value. Different apps put different sets of custom properties there, it's not a fixed set. I'm trying to get all the distinct values each of these fields can have, with the same query - no hard-coded names.

For example, I can use this query to get the distinct counts for one specific table's customDimensions.
(ignore `timestamp`, it's there to compare to the counts of other distinct values)

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| project timestamp, customDimensions
| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)
| summarize count_distinct(InvocationId),
    count_distinct(timestamp),
    count_distinct(Category),
    count_distinct(FullName),
    count_distinct(FunctionExecutionTimeMs),
    count_distinct(HostInstanceId),
    count_distinct(InvocationId),
    count_distinct(LogLevel)
```

The query returns what I need:
[image: Distinct counts per column]

The problem is I need to know all the possible field names before I issue this query, and I want a single query to do this.

I can get the names of all the fields like this:

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| project timestamp, customDimensions
| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)
| getschema 
| project ColumnName
```

The query above returns field names:

[image: Custom property names]

**Is there a way to construct a single query that takes the distinct count for all custom properties?**

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
let column_names = toscalar(
requests
| project timestamp, customDimensions
| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)
| getschema
| summarize make_set(ColumnName)
);
print query = strcat(
"requests |where timestamp > ago(7d)| project timestamp, customDimensions| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)| summarize count_distinct(",
strcat_array(column_names, "),\ncount_distinct("),
")");
```

This query first gets the schema of the  `customDimensions`  property using the  `getschema`  operator. It then uses the  `make_set`  operator to get a list of all the distinct column names in the schema. Finally, required query is generated by concatenatinating all the column names together using the  `strcat_array`  operator. `summarize`  counts the distinct values for each of the columns.

**Output**

| query |
| --- |
| requests |where timestamp > ago(7d)| project timestamp, customDimensions| evaluate bag_unpack(customDimensions)| summarize count_distinct(timestamp), count_distinct(Category), count_distinct(FullName), count_distinct(FunctionExecutionTimeMs) |

You can copy the resulting query data and execute it to get the desired result.

[fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA43QsU4DMQwG4D1PYd2USNkZKlhg5gmQIte1rqGX5LAdUFEfntAKUXWqN1u/pc9e2IDa0ktNFQsrPII1JVxQvBP+6Kym7gSrtHcmA8sjZFjWCNTVWnkZg6q51d8Uf+LS0Ri2OKdeV6SDv42FkZvZlPZcEEajvRSU/M1Q8MBJ2fzzWfQ6QMGFjVslV4NhkePwqQmheQejpj8inL72LPzvgyfAufmHXbgLf6f9WkutV0u7rJYrmZ8inEkXXkIRPPrr10aYQnyrt2shXi4JU9j8AEy577qOAQAA)

Comment: This produces the query I need, but I still need a second call to run the query. Constructing the query by another query is close, but not what I'm looking for - I could run two separate queries from my page's code where the first one gets the field names to construct the second one. I'm looking for a way to get a set of {fieldName, distinctCount} in one call

Comment: There is no `execute` function in Kusto (like sp_executesql in SQL), to execute the dynamically created queries. Thus, instead of creating manually the set of field names and count in the second query, I thought of creating the dynamic query and then executing it manually.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `execute` - maybe there's some way to request `count_distinct` for a set of column names that are put in the `column_names` variable? I haven't found such yet. Making two requests to the server is my issue - it doesn't matter how the second query is generated if there has to be a second query

Comment: I tried giving set of column names in the count_distinct. The expression in count_distinct can have only scalar type data. So, using count_distinct , it is not possible. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/count-distinct-aggfunction#parameters)